# unable to change the items based on id and expected result should be in output format

Tags: javascript

unable to change the items based on id and expected result should be in output format

```js
const items = [
        { id: 1, value: "first" },
        { id: 2, value: "second" },
        { id: 3, value: "third" }
      ];
      const expectedOutput = [
{ id: 1, value: "first" },
        { id: 2, value: "newvalue" },
        { id: 3, value: "third" }
]
      function getData(value, id) {
       return items.map((_each)=> {
         if(_each.id === id) {
           //need to update items with id=2
         }
       })
      }
      
      console.log(getData("newvalue", 2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let inputArr = {
  "data": [{
      "id": 1,
      "value": "first",
      "row": "A"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "value": "second",
      "row": "A"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "value": "Third",
      "row": "B"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "value": "Fourth",
      "row": "B"
    }
  ]
}

function format(inputArr) {
  let arr = []
  let obj = {};
  inputArr.data.forEach(el => {
    obj = {
      ...obj,
      [el.row]: [...(obj[el.row] || []) , el.value],
    }

  });
  arr.push(obj);
  return arr;
}
let outputArr = format(inputArr)
console.log(outputArr)

let expectedOutput = [{
  "A": ["first", "second"]
}, {
  "B": ["Third", "Fourth"]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

@chidananda,
Map callback should return updated item. Minor modification to your code would work!

```js
const items = [
        { id: 1, value: "first" },
        { id: 2, value: "second" },
        { id: 3, value: "third" }
      ];
      const expectedOutput = [
{ id: 1, value: "first" },
        { id: 2, value: "newvalue" },
        { id: 3, value: "third" }
]
      function getData(value, id) {
       return items.map((_each)=> {
         if(_each.id === id) {
           _each.value = value;
         }
         return _each; // Return the modified item
       })
      }
      
      console.log(getData("newvalue", 2))
```